# linux-headers for 5.4.0 charge 38gb

Tags: linux-headers

I'm trying to update my kernel's headers (Linux 5.4.0)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

but apparently, it wants to install allll kinds of headers for all kinds of kernels... and charges 38gb. [(see here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc89m.png)
Going for

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

exits with the error

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.4.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.4.0'
```

Any ideas what I should be doing?

**Background on this:** I'm trying to install wireguard module but because the headers for 5.4.0 aren't apparent, it installs under a different kernel. I can't default when booting because I'm renting a server.

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165929/install-linux-headers-on-debian-unable-to-locate-package).
`sudo apt-get update` # This will update the repositories list
`sudo apt-get upgrade` # This will update all the necessary packages on your system
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` # This will add/remove any needed packages
`reboot` # You may need this since sometimes after a upgrade/dist-upgrade, there are some left over entries that get fixed after a reboot
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` # This should work now

Comment: Thanks for the response but that's not what I'm looking for. This still doesn't work and I think it's because all the headers I see are something like "5.4.0-xxx" but my kernel is just 5.4.0. That's it. Nothing extra. So it tries to get all kinds of headers. But there isn't a right one apparently.